# calc() 100% + #px

Tags: css, css-calc

I'm trying to achieve something I'm not even too sure is possible here.

I'm trying to place a particular drop shadow PNG image under the nav for my site. However I also want to reuse this ability for any object I wish on the site, be it an image, a div or button. Basically use the same shadow image for any object.

Using the css3 `calc()` function I'm attempting to do height of the object @ 100% + 25px (height of png).

I have tried styling:

```
height: -webkit-calc(100% + 25px); 
height:    -moz-calc(100% + 25px); 
height:      -o-calc(100% + 25px);
```

But from what I can gather in Firebug 100% + 25px is then the new 100% as this achieves nothing.

I also tried:

```
height: -webkit-calc(100% + 25px); 
height:    -moz-calc(100% + 25px); 
height:      -o-calc(100% + 25px); 
background-position: 0 -moz-calc(100% + 25px);
```

But no joy here either.

If I use calc(3em + 25px); it works no problem, but this isn't flexible enough to work on any object.

Is this even possible? Am I even making sense?!

Comment: '-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;'

Will that not work better?

Comment: Thanks very much, however this is a specific image I'm using for a curved drop shadow. I had already done box-shadow as a CSS property, however it's not quite the effect I'm after.

Comment: If I understand right, use  
'border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;' to created curved corners. The shadow will follow that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but the [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) describes that the operators on both sides of a calculation form a sub expression (of a single type).

Since you're combining a relative value (%) with a absolute value (px) it might not be able to complete the calculations.

**Update:** I did a small test and it seems too work fine. Are you sure your selectors and positions in the html are correct? Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snpXz/).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much Damien! By putting the shadow div within the Nav element and giving the Nav element a fixed height the shadow is showing perfectly at the bottom. A few niggly margin clashes to sort out but this has worked very nicely indeed! Many Many thanks!

Comment: Just to point out. The test of % against px is flawed, given the fact that you are using 100px height in the first place, as 100% + 25% is the same as 100% + 25px.  A correct test would use an initial height of something other than 100px.  That said, changing the height in the fiddle to 300px does demonstrate that the test does work as expected.

Comment: as above, the problem that happens here is that it automatically chooses the measurement of the first parameter, so in this case it is running (100% + 25px = 125px), which just happens to be the same result as 100% + 25px.
It's just a coincidence they arrive at the same result, at different heights it wouldn't work